# Getting ASP on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, asp

How do you get ASP to work on Google App Engine? I have tried to put ASP code on a webpage but it just showed like it was normal text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google app engine does not support ASP](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#language):

> Currently, Google App Engine supports Java, Python, PHP, and Go. Additionally, your website templates can include JavaScript along with your HTML which, among other things, allows you to write AJAX-enabled web applications.